# How to build CPython for Android?

Tags: android, python, cpython

I want to port some algorithms written on Python to Android. The algorithms don't use any OS specific staff, only several CPython modules for data processing. And I don't want to use some heavy frameworks like kivy. Are there any easy way to build cpython for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find how to build it. But I downloaded Crystax NDK and found out python libraries already compiled and just copied them to my project.

Comment: Hello, What lib do you used? The ./sources/python/3.5/libs/armeabi-v7a/libpython3.5m.so? I tried the so, but throw an runtime exception when I call Py_Initialize.